# In R how to combine dataframes

Tags: arrays, r, loops, dataframe

I am a complete novice when it comes to R and posting on here so apologies in advance. What I am trying to do is combine 2 dataframes

```
data <- seq(0,1000)
info <- data.frame(x,a,b)
```

where info can have up to approx. 50,000 rows. What I need to do is divide each entry in data by each x in info and then work use pbeta with the answer. eg

```
data[1,1] = 1
```

and

```
info$x = seq(1:10)
```

then I would need

```
sum(pbeta(1/1,a,b), pbeta(1/2,a,b), pbeta(1/3,a,b) ... pbeta(1/10,a,b))
```

At the moment I am using a loop to go through each element of data and perform the calculations. Is there a way to avoid using a loop. Shown below

```
while (value <= max)
{x<-(value/info$x);
alp<-(info$Alpha);
bet <-(info$beta);
rat<-(info$rate);
ans <-(1/(1-exp(-1*(sum((1-pbeta(x,alp,bet))*r)))));
data <- rbind(data,data.frame(ans, value));
value <- (value + ((max-1)/1000));
}
```

Apologies for my lack of knowledge on this and how to post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is confusing me because it doesn't seem to do what you describe before. However, maybe this is helpful:

```
data <- (1:5)/10
info <- data.frame(x = 1:3, a = 1 + (1:3)/10, b = 1 - (1:3)/10)

vapply(data, function(x, info) sum(pbeta(x/info$x, info$a, info$b)), 
       info = info, 
       FUN.VALUE = 0.1)
#[1] 0.1009253 0.2234949 0.3571645 0.4994744 0.6493979
```

Comment: Roland, thanks very much for that. Apologies for the confusion. What you gave me worked, but was not much quicker than the loop. I wonder if that is due to the amount of calculation that I am having to perform. Thanks once again.